# 1D Hermitian Hamiltonians are topologically trivial?

Tags: topological-insulators, topological-order

I am currently studying the following paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07435
The authors state:
"The Z/2 classification we found for separable nonHermitian Hamiltonians in one dimension is in contrast with the case of **gapped Hermitian Hamiltonians, all of which are topologically trivial.**"

Yet, I remember that the models like the Su-Schriefer-Heeger(SSH) model, which is 1D has a non-trivial winding number (equal to 1D Chern number) with a Z classification.

How do the two reconcile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement cited is misleading. If the system is bosonic, and no symmetry is considered, then indeed all gapped Hermitian Hamiltonians are trivial. With symmetry there can be distinct symmetry-protected topological (SPT) phases. For fermionic systems, even without symmetry there is a $Z_2$ classification for gapped Hermitian Hamiltonians. SSH model is an example of SPT in fermionic  systems.